# Reboot history in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: data-recovery, logging, ubuntu-16.04, evince

I am trying to recover after a crash of Ubuntu 16.04. The crashed session had been up for several months. Unfortunately, wtmp logs are updated every month. Where can I still find the reboot history, more concretely the date when the previous, the crashed, session had started? Can I extract this information from Zeitgeist, for example?

Comment: FYI: Duplicate Q on askubuntu https://askubuntu.com/questions/1102714/last-reboot-when-it-was-a-long-time-ago with different account https://askubuntu.com/users/905168/d-t

Answer (score 1):

I do not know about Zeitgeist, but if you only want to know what happened, I would have a glance at the logs.

Usually most general stuff is in /var/log/syslog and even in Ubuntu logrotate is set up by default. So you'll find older logs named syslog.1.gz in packed form in the /var/log directory.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, syslog's are very short. They barely cover a week. Zeitgeist contains references to the files which I used very long time ago. So the answer may lie there. Unfortunately, I can find data in Zeitgeist ordered by "timestamp". I do not see how to extract an unexpected shutdown event from them.